# Radio Button is not selected when clicked on listview row

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter, custom-adapter

I have a custom listview adapter which contains one textview and one radio button and I am using it to populate my listview. Now everything is working fine but the problem I am facing is I am unable to select the radiobutton when I click any listview row.I have tried different codes like

[How to set radiobutton unchecked in adapter class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633967/how-to-set-radiobutton-unchecked-in-adapter-class)

[Android ListView with RadioButton/CheckBox in singleChoice mode and a custom row layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842349/android-listview-with-radiobutton-checkbox-in-singlechoice-mode-and-a-custom-row?rq=1)
[conditions on radiobuttons in custom listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872896/conditions-on-radiobuttons-in-custom-listview?rq=1)
on the internet but they didn't helped me. Can anybody help me with this problem ?

This is my adapter class:

```
public class Adapterclass extends BaseAdapter
{

private Context mContext;
private List<String> items;
public String selectedUrl = "";
private RadioButton mSelectedRB;
private int selected = -1;
private String title = "";

public Adapterclass(Context c, List<String> items)
{
    this.mContext = c;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    return this.items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position)
{
    return this.items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    //Count=Size of ArrayList.
    return this.items.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View child, ViewGroup parent)
{
    TextView Title;
    final RadioButton btnradio;
    boolean[] mStarStates = new boolean[0];

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    if (child == null) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cell, null);
    }

    Title = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.sound_title);
    btnradio = (RadioButton) child.findViewById(R.id.radioSelectButton);
    title = this.items.get(position);
    Title.setText(title);
    btnradio.setTag(title);

    btnradio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            if(position != selected && mSelectedRB != null){
                mSelectedRB.setChecked(false);
            }

            selected = position;
            mSelectedRB = (RadioButton)view;
            selectedUrl = (String)view.getTag();
            //notifyDataSetInvalidated();
        }
    });

    if(selected != position){
        btnradio.setChecked(false);
    }else{
        btnradio.setChecked(true);
        if(btnradio != null && btnradio != mSelectedRB){
            mSelectedRB = btnradio;
        }
    }
    return child;
}
 }
```

Do I need to use radioGroup for one radiobutton. or there is a solution to what I am trying to do.
Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: dont use listener on radio button, just set radio button checked or unchecked on the list view item click.

Comment: @Akshay can you tell me how to do that exactly because I am not that good with custom listviews ?
although I have tried it using without listener but it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Answer Found...! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534312/how-to-set-radio-button-to-checked-when-i-click-on-list-item